# javax.servlet.Filter for specific request methods

Tags: java, http, servlets, filter

Is it possible to apply filters to every POST (or combination of HTTP actions) in the application or desired mapping?

Example web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <display-name>AccessFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>foo.bar.AccessFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>AccessFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And I have a controller that maps the following URLs:

- [GET]  /foo/
- [GET]  /foo/:id
- [POST] /foo
- [POST] /bar
- [PUT]  /bar/:id

For example.

Could I apply this filter JUST to the URLs which are POSTs?

Motivation: Only let the owners of the resources modify them, but let everyone consume them.

Answer (score 3):

Check for request `method` in `Filter` as shown below and do what ever you want to do.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse,
        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

    String method = httpServletRequest.getMethod(); //post or get

}
```

Comment: The question wasn't asked right... I wanted to avoid doing this for simplicity.

Comment: Based on URL and Method you can forward the request to the next level or just send a Error page.